# How to execute git ant task without errors

Tags: git, ant

I have created small macro definition for git clone in ant task(build.xml) like below:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="fileCopy">

    <target name="fileCopy" depends="file-checks, local-file, git-file"/>

    <target name="file-checks">
       <available file="rdbms1.properties"  property="file.found"/>
    </target>

    <target name="local-file" if="file.found">
        <echo message="File is available in Local" />
    </target>
    <target name="git-file" unless="file.found">
        <git command="clone" options="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/ant.git"/>
    </target>
    <macrodef name="git">
        <attribute name="command" />
        <attribute name="options" default="" />
        <attribute name="dir" default="" />
        <attribute name="failerror" default="false" />
        <element name="args" optional="true" />
        <sequential>
            <echo message="git dir @{dir}" />
            <echo message="git @{command}" />
            <exec executable="git" dir="@{dir}" failonerror="@{failerror}">
                <arg line="@{command} @{options}" />
                <args />
            </exec>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
</project>
```

but getting exception like below:

```
C:\Users\Haritha\Desktop\H2H\conf\build.xml:14: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Haritha\Desktop\H2H\conf\build.xml:25: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

How to solve this issue to execute my git ant task successfully without any errors??

Comment: is git on your path?

Comment: @almas shaikh..Yes, now i have set git path in environment variables .. it is working now.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add bin path of git.exe (something like C:\Users\Haritha\Desktop\git\bin) to PATH variable like below. To make it permanent change, you could add it as environment variable if you are using Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options, depending on your preference.

1. Add Git.exe path to build.properties file
2. Hard code the executable into the ANT script

Option 1: add property value to build.properties file and replace the executable "git" with "${gitEXE}" in the build.xml file.

Note: We are using the git.exe in the cmd directory of c:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe

**build.properties**

gitEXE=c:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe

```
<macrodef name="git">
    <attribute name="command" />
    <attribute name="options" default="" />
    <attribute name="dir" default="" />
    <attribute name="failerror" default="false" />
    <element name="args" optional="true" />
    <sequential>
        <echo message="git dir @{dir}" />
        <echo message="git @{command}" />
        <exec executable="${gitEXE}" dir="@{dir}" failonerror="@{failerror}">
            <arg line="@{command} @{options}" />
            <args />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Option 2: Hard code executable. Option 1 is preferred.

```
<macrodef name="git">
    <attribute name="command" />
    <attribute name="options" default="" />
    <attribute name="dir" default="" />
    <attribute name="failerror" default="false" />
    <element name="args" optional="true" />
    <sequential>
        <echo message="git dir @{dir}" />
        <echo message="git @{command}" />
        <exec executable="c:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe" dir="@{dir}" failonerror="@{failerror}">
            <arg line="@{command} @{options}" />
            <args />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```